Docker http://localhost:8080/ not respon
I'm trying to develop new CodeIgniter 4 in Docker Desktop, it run in Docker(Containers tab), but not showing(respon) in browser page while I type  http://localhost:8080/ (This page isn’t working)....this is my docker-compose.yml
version: '3.7'
services:
    app:
        build: .
        ports:
            - "8080:8080"
        volumes:
            - ./:/app

and this is my Dockerfile :
FROM docker.io/library/php:8.2-fpm-alpine

RUN apk add --no-cache --update php-curl php-pdo_mysql php-gd php-intl php-json composer
RUN which composer

# Set working directory
WORKDIR /app

# Install required extensions
RUN apk add --no-cache --update \
    php-curl \
    php-pdo_mysql \
    php-gd \
    php-intl \
    php-json \
    php-mbstring \
    php-openssl \
    php-zip \
    php-ctype

# Copy composer files and install dependencies
COPY composer.json composer.lock ./
RUN composer install --no-interaction --prefer-dist --no-dev

# Copy project files
COPY . .

# Expose port
EXPOSE 8080

# Command to run the application
CMD ["php-fpm"]

I don't know what's wrong with my script ?
